# How to run React native program

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a simple react native program on android. I am using [this link](https://school.shoutem.com/lectures/build-react-native-mobile-app-tutorial) but how can I use simulator to run any program? I am using `react-native run-android` but how can I proceed further ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately [questions asking for: books, libraries, tutorials, tools, or other off-site resource are off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and should be closed. Stack Overflow is a [Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) website for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

The command `react-native run-android` does not install or launch any emulator by it's own.
To use an emulator you must first install one. 
Examples are Android Studio and Genymotion.

React-native has it's own instructions on how to install and run react-native on a emulator. You can find it here: [Link](https://school.shoutem.com/lectures/build-react-native-mobile-app-tutorial/)

Follow the instructions under "*Building Projects with Native Code*".